# List IDs That Aren't in An Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SELECT statement that provides me with a list of relevant IDs and company names that match the criteria.  Here is the statement:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.OWNER_ID,b.ID, b.TITLE AS companyname FROM b_crm_act a INNER JOIN b_crm_company b ON a.OWNER_ID = b.ID");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This lists all the IDs and company names. What I actually need is a list of IDs from b_crm_company that aren't in b_crm_act.  I'm thinking I use NOT IN function but I've tried this and it's not listing anything.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `LEFT JOIN` on this

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
        a.TITLE AS companyname 
FROM    b_crm_company a 
        LEFT JOIN b_crm_act b 
            ON a.ID = b.OWNER_ID // <== specify how the tables are linked
WHERE   b.OWNER_ID IS NULL       // <== a value of NULL when it doesn't exists
```

*Not sure about your column names but this is how it looks like.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient this is but have you tried using a NOT IN subquery?

```
SELECT ID,title FROM b_crm_company WHERE ID NOT IN( SELECT ID FROM b_crm_company INNER JOIN b_crm_act ON b_crm_act.OWNER_ID = b_crm_company.ID )
```